# Does installing Jakeday kernel break Ubuntu update?

Tags: 18.04, kernel

I'm running Ubuntu on my Surface book and its working pretty well.  'Im considering installing Jake Day's patched kernel for Surface, but if I do so does that mean I can no longer use Ubuntu system updates?

Comment: "its working pretty well". Why fix something that is not broken? "but if I do so does that mean I can no longer use Ubuntu system updates?"  why don't you tell us? I would assume hardly anyone here uses that kernel since most of us wont have a surface pro.

Comment: Well there are a few anomalies that the kernel; seems rto help with,  I installed it in parallel so I can go back to the LTS one if I need to.

So far its working just fine.  I guess we will see what happens next time there are major updates.